# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Using Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento-1.8, owl-carousel

I'm using the Owl Carousel on a Magento site and I can get the slides showing properly, but cannot control the slider using any of it's functions... here's my html code:

```
<div id="main-slider" class="owl-carousel mobile-slider">
<div class="item">{{block type="cms/block" block_id="block_slide1"}}</div>
<div class="item">{{block type="cms/block" block_id="block_slide2"}}</div>
<div class="item">{{block type="cms/block" block_id="block_slide3"}}</div>
<div class="item">{{block type="cms/block" block_id="block_slide4"}}</div>
<div class="item">{{block type="cms/block" block_id="block_slide5"}}</div>
</div>
```

And here's my controls that I placed directly after the above html:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#main-slider').owlCarousel({

    singleItem: true,
    slideSpeed: 200,
    stopOnHover: true,
    navigation: true
  }); 
});
```

And here's the error in console that I'm returning:

[image: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function]

In my header I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/nwdthemes/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/nwdthemes/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/nwdthemes/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nwdthemes/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nwdthemes/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the output of the carousel, 'singleItem: true' doesn't seem to work as it's showing 2 slides at once:

[image]

Comment: To me that means `owlCarousel` is undefined. Where is your reference to the script that defines the owlCarousel plugin?

Comment: Just edited what I have in my header to include the script

Comment: Why is the code in your console output different that the code have directly after your html? Did you not post all of the code after your html or is this a different spot?

Comment: The screenshot of the console error is a bit older from when I copied and pasted the my code into the question here, The main thing that I'm wanting to work is 'singleItem: true'  , as right now if you view the carousel, it's showing multiple slides at once on larger devices / desktop, instead of just 1 at a time

Comment: I'll add though that no matter what the controls are set to, I get the same "Uncaught TypeError" and none of the control settings reflect on the output of the carousel.

Comment: does the resource at `js/nwdthemes/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js` actually exist?

Comment: Yes, I verified that each resource exists and linked properly.

Comment: Can you post the order of the script loading? Please check whether owl script is loading after your script file.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    // ...
    stopOnHover: false,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Please, always give some explanation and not only the plain code